# If data has linear frelationship, won't linear regression lead to zero in-sample error

Tags: machine-learning, linear-regression

I am using the Learning from Data textbook by Yaser Abu-Mostafa et al.  I am curious about the following statement in the linear regression chapter and would like to verify that my understanding is correct.

After talking about the "pseudo-inverse" way to get the "best weights" (best for minimizing squared error), i.e `w_lin = (X^T X)^-1 X^T y`

The statement is "The linear regression weight vector is an attempt to map the inputs X to the outputs y.  However, `w_lin` does not produce `y` exactly, but produces an estimate `X w_lin` which differs from `y` due to in sample error.

If the data is on a hyper-plane, won't `X w_lin` exactly match `y` (i.e in-sample error = 0)?   I.e above statement is only talking about data that is not linearly separable.

Answer (score 1):

Here, 'w_lin' is the not the same for all data points (all pairs of (X,y)).

The linear regression model finds the best possible weight vector (or best possible 'w_lin') considering all data points such that X*w_lin  gives a result very close to 'y' for any data point.

Hence the error will not be zero unless all data points line on a straight line.

Comment: I find it difficult to agree on this "Hence the error will not be zero unless all data points line on a straight line." Error may or may not be zero.

Answer (score 1):

The community might not get whole context unless the book is opened because not everything that the author of the book says might have been covered in your post. But let me try to answer.

Whenever any model is formed, there are certain constants used whose value is not known beforehand but are used to fit the line/curve as good as possible. Also, the equations, many a times, contain an element of randomness. Variables that take random values cause some errors when actual and expected outputs are computed.

Suggested reading: [Errors and residuals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Errors_and_residuals)